# How to sign outgoing emails with DKIM private key

Tags: dkim, domainkeys

I generated DKIM for my domain and I received one public key and one private key. I updated my public key value in my DNS and now I have the private key leftover with me. How to use this private key? How to sign my outgoing emails with this DKIM private key?

I am running Windows 2003 server with Plesk installed. Anybody please tell me where and how to add my private key to enable email signing.

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation! It has been answered already. And not that this is way off topic here.

http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PPP9/Doc/en-US/plesk-9.0-administrators-guide/59433.htm

Even look on to the right side with all the related questions and their answers.

**Edit**:
Sorry forget about the answer above. Domainkeys is *not* DKIM. And Plesk only allows Domainkeys. So you are lost here. There is no way to do it with Plesk.

Comment: So? what should I do now in order to add my DKIM?

Comment: Complain at Parallels. But others have done it for no luck. Change the mail software, add third-party software, don't sign mails, switch operating system, ... There are many options but no "DKIM and Plesk"-option.